# Temporally synchronize two different or more real time digital audio signals

Tags: digital-communications, audio-processing, array-signal-processing

Are there any DSP techniques to temporally synchronize two different or more real-time digital audio signals without timestamp information?

Comment: if they are similar enough, you can try to estimate the delay using cross correlation. one van also use heuristics based on the structure of the signals, like trying to match pauses that might be present in all the signals. It is usually better to design a system appropriately than using processing as an act of desperation

Comment: Thank you @StanleyPawlukiewicz. I'll look into your technique.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, the structure/details of the audio signals are:

PCM 16-bit digital audio signal, mono with the sampling frequency of 8000.
Programmatically, a byte array of 640 bytes of data.